# Open and Closed Sets in the Euclidean Space R^n

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $F_1, F_2, ..., F_k$ are closed sets in $R^{n},$ then $\cup_{i = 1}^{k}F_i$ is also a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$

Comment: See any text book of Metric space

Comment: OP, you should consider adding more of your own thoughts. It prevents you from getting downvotes and helps others see what you see, and therefore see how to help.

Comment: Please search before asking. "finite union of closed sets" brings multiple results

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** First show that the intersection of finitely many open sets is open, then take the compliment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** This can be generalized. If $A,B$ are closed subsets of a topological space $X$, then $X\setminus A$, $X\setminus B$ are open in $X$. Then $(X\setminus A)\cap(X\setminus B)$ is open in $X$, so $X\setminus[(X\setminus A)\cap(X\setminus B)]$ is closed in $X$. But that set is just $A\cup B$. Now use an inductive argument to show that a finite union of closed subsets of $X$ is closed in $X$.